# Possible differences between 2 identical Docker containers

Tags: docker, containers

I have modified docker container with some installed and configurated software, which I commit in image and push to Docker Hub:

```
docker commit 38c61c8ac3c3 image_name
docker push docker_hub_account/my_repo
```

Then I delete all containers and try to run container from my new base image -

```
sudo docker run -ti -p 8081:8080 docker_hub_account/my_repo /bin/bash
```

On my machine everything works fine, but when someone try to pull this image and run they got an error with license.

I find out only one difference between this 2 containers - different MAC address, so I specify it:

```
sudo docker run -ti -p 8081:8080 --mac-address=02:42:ac:11:00:02 docker_hub_account/my_repo /bin/bash
```

What else could be different?

Comment: IP address, interface name, mac address, `/etc/mtab`, `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hostname` `uname -a` `/proc` `/sys`, `/dev`.  I would hazard a guess that if your software needs a license and has a check for it, you shouldn't be distributing it via docker or on docker hub.

Comment: @Matt it's private repo just for internal tests

Comment: Sure, but the license check implies that docker usage might be outside the license? If not, you may need to configure the license on startup rather than in the base image.